# Adobe PDF IFilter in 32 bit machine

Tags: c#, ifilter

I am indexing `PDF` file in an application, using PDF IFilter 6.0, and I am getting the following exception:

```
System.AccessViolationException: 
Attempted to read or write protected memory. 
This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.    

at EPocalipse.IFilter.IFilter.Init(IFILTER_INIT grfFlags, Int32 cAttributes, IntPtr aAttributes, IFILTER_FLAGS& pdwFlags)    
at EPocalipse.IFilter.FilterLoader.LoadAndInitIFilter(String fileName, String extension)
at EPocalipse.IFilter.FilterLoader.LoadAndInitIFilter(String fileName)    
at EPocalipse.IFilter.FilterReader..ctor(String fileName)
```

I am using Win 7 32 bit machine. Does PDF IFilter works on Win 7?

My application is multi threaded, does Ifilter works with multi-threading? I also tried using `STAThread` but got the same exception. Also tried putting lock while instantiating the Reader but no lock.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot multithread the Adobe IFilter, it is designed for Single Thread appartement.

Use IFilter Explorer to know which IFilter is STA: http://www.citeknet.com/Products/IFilters/IFilterExplorer/tabid/62/Default.aspx

The solution you can use, if you wanna keep your app multithreaded for other filters, is to spin a thread that you dedicate to STA IFilters and keep it around for the lifetime of the application. You then always process your documents that need STA in that same thread.